# Unity - Mirror Networking : Player client disconnect after scene changed

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

I'm currently using Mirror Networking to make a multiplayer game. I have a scene when players are all connected, they can choose their characters and set the ready. If all players are ready, I change current scene to arena scene using MyNetworkManager.ServerChangeScene(arenaSceneName). This method sets all player clients as not ready. But After the scene was loaded, my player client is no longer connected to my host and I don't know why.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Clients that connect to this server will automatically switch to this scene. This is called automatically if onlineScene or offlineScene are set, but it can be called from user code to switch scenes again while the game is in progress. This automatically sets clients to be not-ready. The clients must call **NetworkClient.Ready** again to participate in the new scene."

if its not solve problem  can you  give more information about your project
Are you using MatchInterestManager ? This can be lead some problems like yours

Edit 1 -
Maybe the problem was host
can you run your code on server not host

Edit 2 -
i belive your command function runs on client not server because you miss "Cmd" prefix on your command function change it CmdOnAllPlayersReady()

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249017/discussion-on-answer-by-catpawnd20-unity-mirror-networking-player-client-dis).

Comment: Let's go to continue to find solution in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReadyPlayerChecker : NetworkBehaviour
{
  public List<PlayerBehaviour> activePlayers;

  public List<PlayerBehaviour> GetActivePlayers()
  {
    return activePlayers;
  }

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    activePlayers = new List<PlayerBehaviour>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    foreach (PlayerBehaviour player in FindObjectsOfType<PlayerBehaviour> 
    (true))
    {
       if(!activePlayers.Contains(player))
       {
          activePlayers.Add(player);
       }
    }

    bool allPlayersReady = true;
    foreach (PlayerBehaviour player in activePlayers)
    {
       if (!player.IsReady())
       {
          allPlayersReady = false;
       }
    }
    if (allPlayersReady && activePlayers.Count > 0)
    {
       OnAllPLayersReady();
    }
 }

 [Command]
 public void OnAllPLayersReady()
 {
    GameObject.Find("SceneManager").GetComponent<SceneChanger> 
    ().LoadScene("SimpleArena");
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is my Network Manager settings :

[image: My Network Manager settings]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to make the playerclient connected when the scene change. Now, the player prefab for my client is in host view but not in the corresponding client view. Do someone can tell me why ?